# Which Environments Should Integration Test be Run In?

Tags: testing, integration-testing

Given a development pipeline with playground, staging, and production environments, which environment is most appropriate for integration tests? What is the best practice around this?

My thinking is that it should be in the playground environment, to get the earliest results (ie shift left). However, I have also seen some examples of re-running integration tests for each environment.

Is there value in running integration tests multiple times, or does it make more sense to just run it once in an appropriate environment?

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a standard best practice, it also depends on the application and the testing setup you have.

You can skip running tests on the production environment as it will affect the performance for your users. Also it is not a good idea to put testing data into your production environment. To test out whether the functionality is working fine on production, you can create an environment which mimics the production environment.

Since different environment like QA/Staging can have different environment configuration and different CPU/Memory settings, it is a good idea to run the integration tests on multiple environments.

Answer (score 0):

Integration tests are best done by creating a new environment on the go and deleting in the end. Only the test results and errors should be logged and kept saved.
An option should be provided to keep the environment for debugging purposes or not.

More details can be found here in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75938284/1501191